# PHP CSV to Array with headings and id as group-key

Tags: php, arrays, csv

i have a csv-file where i have headings. the first column has a unique id.

im using following code for the output in arays and headings as keys:

```php
function csv_to_array($filename='', $delimiter=',') {
    if(!file_exists($filename) || !is_readable($filename))
        return FALSE;

    $header = NULL;
    $data = array();
    if (($handle = fopen($filename, 'r')) !== FALSE)
    {
        while (($row = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, $delimiter)) !== FALSE)
        {
            if(!$header)
                $header = $row;
            else
                $data[] = array_combine($header, $row);
        }
        fclose($handle);
        
    }
    return $data;
}
```

Now i get the output

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [﻿id] => 2548
            [description ] => MyDescription
            [value] => 5
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [﻿id] => 2549
            [description ] => MyDescription
            [value] => 10
        )
```

i want to put the "id" as key for the group array like

```
Array
(
    [2548] => Array
        (
            [﻿id] => 2548
            [description ] => MyDescription
            [value] => 5
        )
    [2549] => Array
```

but i cant call the id one group before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just grab the ID first an put it into the `$data` array as an index. Do you want to keep the ID in the data? See the comments in the code

```php
function csv_to_array($filename='', $delimiter=',') {
    if(!file_exists($filename) || !is_readable($filename))
        return FALSE;

    $header = NULL;
    $data = array();
    if (($handle = fopen($filename, 'r')) !== FALSE)
    {
        while (($row = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, $delimiter)) !== FALSE)
        {
            if(!$header)
                $header = $row;
            else{
                $id = $row[0]; // grab the ID from the row / expectiong that the ID is in the first column of your CSV
                //unset($row[0]); // <-- uncomment this line if you want to remove the ID from the data array
                $data[$id] = array_combine($header, $row);
            }
                
        }
        fclose($handle);

    }
    return $data;
}
```

Comment: Oh thank you very much, thats working fine! The possibility to unset the id is also very usefull!